# how to do multitasking from same code at the same time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms

Sorry if the title is not clear or correct, dont know what title should i put. Please correct if wrong.
I have this code to download images from IP camera and it can download the images.
The problem is how can i do the images downloading process at the same time for all cameras if i have two or more cameras?

```
private void GetImage()
{
   string IP1 = "example.IPcam1.com:81/snapshot.cgi;
   string IP2 = "example.IPcam2.com:81/snapshot.cgi;
   .
   .
   .
   string IPn = "example.IPcamn.com:81/snapshot.cgi";

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       string ImagePath = Server.MapPath("~\\Videos\\liveRecording2\\") + string.Format("{0}", i, i + 1) + ".jpeg";
       string sourceURL = ip;
       WebRequest req = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
       req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
       WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
       Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
       Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
       bmp.Save(ImagePath);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods that will depend on how you want to report feedback to the user.  It all comes down to multi-threading.

Here is one example, using the `ThreadPool`.  Note that this is missing a bunch of error checking throughout...  It is here as an example of how to use the `ThreadPool`, not as a robust application:

```
private Dictionary<String, String> _cameras = new Dictionary<String, String> {
    { "http://example.IPcam1.com:81/snapshot.cgi", "/some/path/for/image1.jpg" },
    { "http://example.IPcam2.com:81/snapshot.cgi", "/some/other/path/image2.jpg" },
};

public void DoImageDownload() {
    int finished = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> pair in _cameras) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
            BeginDownload(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            finished++;
        });
    }

    while (finished < _cameras.Count) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // sleep 1 second
    }
}

private void BeginDownload(String src, String dest) {
    WebRequest req = (WebRequest) WebRequest.Create(src);
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream input = resp.GetResponseStream();
    using (Stream output = File.Create(dest)) {
        input.CopyTo(output);
    }
}
```

This example simply takes the work you are doing in the for loop and off-loads it to the thread pool for processing.  The `DoImageDownload` method will return very quickly, as it is not doing much actual work.

Depending on your use case, you may need a mechanism to wait for the images to finish downloading from the caller of `DoImageDownload`.  A common approach would be the use of event callbacks at the end of `BeginDownload` to notify when the download is complete.  I have put a simple `while` loop here that will wait until the images finish...  Of course, this needs error checking in case images are missing or the `delegate` never returns.

Be sure to add your error checking throughout...  Hopefully this gives you a place to start.

Comment: How can i get all the links `src` at the same time? `foreach()` should get all the string `scr` but if i provide a source links in 
`string IP1 = "http://example1.com:81/snapshot.cgi";` and 
`"string IP2 = "http://example2.com:81/snapshot.cgi";`, how can i get it in `foreach()` statement? And how can i save the images in separate folders for each cameras so i know which images from which cameras?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example for storing a mapping of IP addresses to path names.  It may not be exact for your needs, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Ok, i copy and paste your code and put `DoImageDownload()` to `Page_Load` and change tthe destination folder for images in the same folder with different name(1.jpg & 2.jpg) for both cameras. I run the code but it download image only from 1 camera(only 1 image in folder). So, i do the breakpoint(visual studio 2010) to see how the process going but confusingly it download and save 2 images in destination folder and the images is correctly from different cameras(not duplicate). I tried it several times but the result is same.

Comment: As I mentioned, you will also need a mechanism to block until the images are downloaded.  Because `DoImageDownload()` returns very quickly, you will need to wait elsewhere in your application until all images have downloaded.  I have added a very basic example to the code above.

Answer (score 3):

You should not run long-running code like that from an ASP.NET application. They are meant to simply respond to requests.

You should place this code in a service (Windows Services are easy), and control the service through a WCF service running inside of it.

You're also going to get into trouble because you don't have your WebResponse and Stream in `using` blocks.

Comment: +1 I missed the `webforms` tag on this...  Wasn't thinking of ASP.NET.